# CMake found Boost but Make cannot find include file

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, cmake

I am currently having a problem with Boost. During CMake stage, it stated clearly that boost was found:

```
-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   iostreams
--   timer
--   system
--   regex
```

But during the `make` stage from the generated `Makefile`:

```
Timer.h(26): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "boost/timer/timer.hpp"
  #include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
[..]                                  ^

Function.h(29): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp"
  #include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>
[..]
```

basically, it doesn't seem like `Makefile` found any header for `boost`. I have even gone and declare `Boost_INCLUDEDIR` and `Boost_LIBRARYDIR` - case sensitive. Doesn't look like it helps.

What could be the possible cause? Could it be some conflicts between the compiler, i.e. `gcc/icc` and the `cmake` generator? (Pure guess - I am not expertised in this area...)

**EDIT**: This is the process of find `boost` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file: http://pastebin.com/7m3yAYk5 and the `FindBOOST.cmake` is here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `CMakeLists.txt` looking for Boost. It is not possible to answer your question without knowing how you are searching and using Boost

Comment: Did you have this `include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finding a library and including it are two different things.

You will need to not only *find* Boost, but include it's headers and link to its libraries. A simple CMakeLists.txt example:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.61 COMPONENTS filesystem program_options iostreams timer REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

ADD_EXECUTABLE( myProgram myMain.cpp )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( myProgram ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

If you have already done this, please update your question to include that information.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows with `find_package(Boost 1.70.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph) ` on Cmake 3.17. Still get cannot open source file... Any ideas?